# What web-based Content Management System (e.g. Blogger) has the best support for chess content?

Tags: software, pgn, chess-blog

I am contemplating starting a website/blog, and trying to choose between Blogger, WordPress, and Drupal (but open to others). My needs are mostly blog-like - to post static pages and regular updates, and I'd like to choose a platform that has good support for embedding FEN/PGN strings/files out the box and generating diagrams and replayable games. I'd also like to link to a static pgn file with many combinations and have a gadget that would display a diagram with a "Daily Tactic". So far I looked into Blogger, and it does not have much support out of the box, and actually makes it difficult/impossible for me to embed Javascript that I have pre-generated with something like PalView. What are my other options?

Comment: Relevant: http://kvchess.com/publish.html. Cheers.

Comment: Any feedback on the answers so far? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at pgn4web?
http://pgn4web.casaschi.net/home.html

It supports adding PGN for replay and I believe Tactics too.
Also supports major platforms like WordPress, blogger.
I have published a simple replayable game with it on blogger and it works like a charm.
http://mychessapps.blogspot.in/2013/12/my-3-min-blitz-game-on-fics.html

Note that pgn4web for Wordpress requires a hosted version of Wordpress on which you can install the plugin; it will not be compatible with a blog hosted at Wordpress.com

Answer (score 1):

I am writing for a [Chess Blog](http://chess-team-viking-swe.blogspot.se/2012/03/secer-fm-sagit-r-sagit.html) (Blogger) from time to time, using [KV Chess (former Chess Flash)](http://kvchess.com/publish.html) to generate replayable chess games. Thus, the viewer is embedded as flash code. I did not manage to use PalView, it seemed a bit too complicated and had bugs. Perhaps it is better today? Cheers.